# Entire Reactstrap Navbar misaligned/inverted using example code

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, reactstrap

I was following the reactstrap example for the first time when trying to set up a Navbar component for my site, and it looks completely different than the shown output. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I was expecting it to look something like (mockup):

[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Collapse, Navbar, NavbarToggler, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

export default class NavigationBar extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    isOpen: false
  };
}

toggle() {
  this.setState({
    isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Container fluid={true}>
        <header>
          <Row>
            <Col sm="12" md="12" lg="12">
              <Navbar className="navbar-inverse" toggleable>
                <NavbarToggler right onClick={this.toggle} />
                <NavbarBrand href="/">
                  My App
                </NavbarBrand>
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                  <Nav navbar>
                    <NavItem>
                      <NavLink href="/settings/">Settings</NavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem>
                      <NavLink href="/logout/">Logout</NavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                  </Nav>
                </Collapse>
              </Navbar>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </header>
      </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

And:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Have you imported `bootstrap.css` in `index.js`?

Comment: @KostasSiabanis Yes, it's imported at the app level in App.js